# A word similar to "Donate" but more freely provided to

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there any other words similar to these words:

Award, Bestow, Donate, Grant, Give, Provide, Tax

...that give a meaning of:  I freely give to you a **portion** what I have acquired or earned, without hesitation or expectation of anything in return. You are owed this, without question. There is no emotion involved with this transaction. It just is what it is.

For example: as a member of the Thief's Guild, 20% of everything you acquire will be ______ to the Guild.

Bestowed and Granted are very close...

Any other ideas?

Comment: ... Will be ***owed*** to the Guild.  Or rewrite:  ... the Guild gets a 20% cut of everything you acquire

Comment: In your example it doesn't sound like there's any choice in handing over the 20%: you either hand over 20% or you get chucked out the guild. You also state "you are owed this", which means there is no choice. So I'm confused as to why you're using "freely".

Comment: Sorry, SED. What you posted isn't clear enough to warrant anything but a guess.

Did you want guesses, or could you rephrase the Question?

Comment: Why is the word *portion* highlighted in this question? Are you suggesting you're looking for a word that specifically includes this idea in its meaning? A word that means "partially surrendered"? Similar to "tithed" except not implying a fraction of exactly one-tenth?

Comment: Please see the [info on word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). We need to see the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Why have you rejected the words you've already found? What register are you looking for -- formal? Legal?

Comment: "Will be [tithed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tithe)" may suit your needs. And unless there's only one Thief, consider Thieves' Guild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***transfer***, [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transfer):

> Make over the possession of (property, a right, or a responsibility)
>   to another.

In the OP's example:

> As a member of the Thief's Guild, 20% of everything you acquire will
>   be transferred to the Guild.