# Looking for a word that means to give for free, but is distinct from "donate"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing about how companies in a particular industry are responding to the Covid-19 situation. I'm categorising their responses and labelling each category with a single word.

Two categories are similar yet different enough to remain distinct. I'm struggling to find single-word labels for them that are sufficiently differentiated. Currently I have:

"Giving" - companies are giving some of their products and services to regular and vulnerable customers for free to help them through the crisis (and of course to generate goodwill, customer loyalty, CSR points, etc.). For example, giving an extra 50% when a customer renews, making premium services freely available for a limited period, etc.

"Donating" - companies are donating money, facilities, employee time, as well as products and services, to governments and health organisations to help them tackle the crisis. For example, donating $X million to relevant charites, making now-empty buildings available for health worker training, giving products and services to organisations working on care, treatment, etc.

Both labels describe their respective activities well, but they overlap too much. Can I replace one with an alternative that reduces this overlap? The best I've come up with so far is to replace "giving" with "subsidising", but that seems a little flaccid in comparison. This is for a business audience and should be clear, impactful, easy to read, etc.

The following thread is close, but doesn't quite answer my question ("Bestowing" may be the best option in that thread, but again is too similar to "donating", and is also a little archaic for my purposes):
[A word similar to "Donate" but more freely provided to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409168/a-word-similar-to-donate-but-more-freely-provided-to)

Comment: How about **hand out**

Comment: In normal usage "give" includes "donate", so all "donations" are also "gifts". What in your mind is an example of something that is "donated" but not "given"?

Comment: I see the main difference as internal and external, so maybe an in-and-out pair, or Deals and Giveaways?

Answer (score -1):

Many companies gave benefits to their regulars before this all started, called reward programs. Therefore the word I suggest you use is *rewarding*.

Here’s an example in use:

> [Wawa rewards customers with new app](https://chainstoreage.com/news/wawa-rewards-customers-new-app)

Comment: Definitely not. "Reward" implies that the thing is in return for something else, even it's it's something is abstract as "being a loyal customer".